# looking for full calendar view for 2.6

Tags: fullcalendar

Is it published now version 2.2.7 year view https://libraries.io/bower/fullcalendar-yearview/v2.2.7-yearview
How can I get year view for 2.6 version?

Comment: Since this is a fork of an older branch, your best bet may be to diff the official 2.2.7 distribution and this one, and apply/re-implement the changes against 2.6.1 - potentially lots of work if someone else hasn't already done so.